# Convert Array of strings to object with no key

Tags: arrays, object, graphql, mule, dataweave

I need to convert the array of strings into an object with no keys.
Input:

```
[
"1234",
"5678"
]
```

Expected Output:

```
query: "{
 key1: mutation(number: "1234"){
number
},
key2: mutation(number: "5678"){
number
}
}"
```

Dataweave:

```
output application/json
---
payload map{
data: "key" ++ ($$+1) ++ ":mutation(number:\"" ++ $ ++ "\"){ number }"
}
```

When I try the above code, not able to remove the data from output and also string is getting split. can somebody help with graphql request.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a string for each element of the array containing the query, then we need to concatenate all the string into one. I used reduce() for that. Then the result is assigned to the `query` element. Note that DataWeave doesn't support GraphQL at this time.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    query: payload map (
            "{key" ++ ($$+1) ++ ":mutation(number:\"" ++ $ ++ "\"){ number }" )reduce ($$ ++ $)
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "query": "{key1:mutation(number:\"1234\"){ number }{key2:mutation(number:\"5678\"){ number }"
}
```